# What is the best way to do HTML encoding and decoding in Apex?

Tags: apex, encodingutil

I am programmatically building a HTML string in Apex and then saving it to a rich text field. The problem is that SalesForce is doing some HTML encoding on the string before it gets persisted which is making the string longer and causing a STRING_TOO_LONG error. What is the best way to do HTML encoding and decoding in Apex? See below for my attempt:

```
public String htmlEncode (String s) {  

    Map<String, String> htmlEncodingMap = new Map<String, String>();
    htmlEncodingMap.put('<', '&lt;');
    htmlEncodingMap.put('>', '&gt;');
    htmlEncodingMap.put('"', '&amp;quot;');
    htmlEncodingMap.put('&', '&amp;');

    for (String token : htmlEncodingMap.keySet()) {
        s = s.replace(token, htmlEncodingMap.get(token));
    }

    return s;
}

public String htmlDecode (String s) {  

    Map<String, String> htmlDecodingMap = new Map<String, String>();
    htmlDecodingMap.put('&lt;', '<');
    htmlDecodingMap.put('&gt;', '>');
    htmlDecodingMap.put('&amp;quot;', '"');
    htmlDecodingMap.put('&amp;', '&');

    for (String token : htmlDecodingMap.keySet()) {
        s = s.replace(token, htmlDecodingMap.get(token));
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: (1) it's `&quot;` not `&amp;quot;`, and (2) are you trying to encode the text from a rich text input? If so, you shouldn't be attempting to escape it yourself.

Comment: Is the character length on a rich text field (eg 32,000 characters) the raw string or is it the length after SF does the HTML encoding it?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's the limitation after any encoding is applied, but I don't remember where I saw that in the documentation.

Comment: I think thats what this question is asking then. They want to encode the text to verify (or truncate) its not over the character limit

Comment: Yes that is correct. I am looking to encode the text to verify its not over the character limit, so i can truncate the string to avoid the STRING_TOO_LONG error if the encoded text is too long.

Comment: Using the debug log I was able view what the double quote is escaped with by wrapping the " with in brackets like so ->("). I have upload the image of the [debug log](http://i.imgur.com/DiVCI8K.png).

Comment: HTMLENCODE function is available in Visualforce, isn't there any way of utilizing the same?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Apex String](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.240.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_methods) class has HTML escape and unescape methods on it, [escapteHtml4](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_escapeHtml4) and [unescapeHtml4](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_unescapeHtml4). Here are some examples from these topics in the documentation...

```apex
String s1 = 
   '"<Black&White>"';
String s2 = 
   s1.escapeHtml4();
System.debug(s2);
// Output:
// &quot;&lt;Black&amp;
// White&gt;&quot;

String s1 = 
   '&quot;&lt;Black&amp;White&gt;&quot;';
String s2 = 
   s1.unescapeHtml4();
System.assertEquals(
   '"<Black&White>"',
   s2);
```

---

*2022.11.18: Updated broken links to SF documentation*

Comment: I looked at this yesterday, and I forgot that the functions were in String. Why couldn't they have put it with, for example, urlencode? Or put it in both places, just for kicks (e.g. System.Now() and DateTime.Now()).

Comment: LOL yeah, I've never seen so many methods on a String class tbh! :)

Comment: Whats the difference between `escapeHtml3` and `escapeHtml4`? The docs don't show any difference

Comment: Anything prefixed with a & (ampersand) in HTML is known as an "entity" for a special character, HTML 3.0 and HTML 4.0 versions had different supported entities. http://f2.org/links/webauth/entities.html#html3

Comment: Andrew to the rescue again... :)

Comment: This doesn't escape "<br>" breaklines.  How do we escape breaks?

Comment: stripHtmlTags() is the solution :)

Comment: Had a similar kind of issue here at - http://goo.gl/DvJG4o 
`unescapeHtml4` actually resolved the issue.. Thanks again.