# Special Characters in rest API URL

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, parameters

Is there any way to handle a & in a params being sent in the URL of a restAPI call. So that the system doesn't think this the end and start of a different params? The URL being sent is below:

/services/apexrest/task?branchId=60521::BAC::London::Finance, Temp & PQ

When viewing the call in the debug log the & PQ is missing the branchId

[image]

If you need any further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to escape it, basically you use the method escapeHtml4() of the class String.

```
String s1 = 
   '"<Mom&Dad>"';
String s2 = 
   s1.escapeHtml4();
System.debug(s2);
// Output:
// &quot;&lt;Mom&amp;Dad&gt;&quot;
```

You can refer to this similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/22245/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-html-encoding-and-decoding-in-apex).

You can find useful the similar concept in another language, for example in [Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript)

Comment: I might suggest `EncodingUtil.urlEncode()` instead, but the gist of it is correct (the characters need to be encoded/escaped)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Its pointed me in the right direction