# How to decode ConnectApi response?

Tags: connect-api, b2b-commerce, b2b, b2b-lex

Based on article: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/intro_encoding.htm

Responses from ConnectApi are by default encoded, they have mentioned in this article how to request raw (unencoded) output, however it's only for HTTP Requests where I can provide X-Chatter-Entity-Encoding to false.

My problem is when I am using for example "ConnectApi.CommerceSearch.searchProducts", there is no way for me to receive unencoded response, I am receiving encoded values like:
`"Tom &amp; Jerry"`
where I am expecting:
`"Tom & Jerry"`.

Is there a way to traverse whole ConnectApi response to find all strings to unencode them or any other solution?

It's a problem because those encoded values are displayed in the filter section on the search results page.
When filters are passed to connectApi to return new results, based on this filter there won't be any results because there is no product matching `"Tom &amp; Jerry"`

Comment: From where are you calling the ConnectApi and trying to parse the response? The documentation at the link you provided states, "The main part of the URL is URL-encoded as per RFC2396, and the query string is HTML-form encoded." Can you not use some built-in decoder(s) in your receiving context?

Comment: Custom component responsible for displaying results, is calling method from the apex controller which executes ConnectApi.CommerceSearch.searchProducts and returns the results to that component.
I was instructed by the SF Support to replace escaped values with their unescaped values, but they pointed that may not be the best solution :)
I am doing regex with replace method on the data in JS controller receives.
It works but I had to be specific which fields I want to replace and to some map() in JS.
How could I use built-in decoder(s)? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: Short answer of potentially helpful Apex: `String` class methods (e.g., `unescapeHtml4()`, `unescapeHtml3()`, `stripHtmlTags()`), `EncodingUtil` class methods (e.g., `urlDecode()`). | Longer potentially helpful answer: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/22295/81648